# create php array from duplicate key value pairs

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json response from backend like this:

```
[{"studentID":"1","subjectID":"2","marks":65},
{"studentID":"1","subjectID":"3","marks":75},
{"studentID":"2","subjectID":"2","marks":80},
{"studentID":"2","subjectID":"3","marks":82},
{"studentID":"3","subjectID":"2","marks":"82"},
{"studentID":"3","subjectID":"3","marks":"75"}]
```

but i want to have it like this:

```
[{"studentID":"1","subjectID":"2","marks":65,"subjectID":"3","marks":75},
{"studentID":"2","subjectID":"2","marks":80,"subjectID":"3","marks":82}
{"studentID":"3","subjectID":"2","marks":"82","subjectID":"3","marks":"75"}]
```

Any idea on how to achieve this from the given array?

Comment: Iterate over array and rebuild it. BTW, you cannot have same keys in array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned you can't have duplicate keys in each object. You need to rebuild it in to something you can use. Something like this maybe:

```
$data = json_decode('[{"studentID":"1","subjectID":"2","marks":65},{"studentID":"1","subjectID":"3","marks":75},{"studentID":"2","subjectID":"2","marks":80},{"studentID":"2","subjectID":"3","marks":82},{"studentID":"3","subjectID":"2","marks":"82"},{"studentID":"3","subjectID":"3","marks":"75"}]');

$students = [];

foreach($data as $d) {
    // If entry for student does not exist, create it
    if(!isset($students[$d->studentID])) {
        $students[$d->studentID] = ["subjects" => []];
    }

    // Add data to correct subject
    $students[$d->studentID]['subjects'][$d->subjectID] = [
        "marks" => $d->marks
    ];
}

echo json_encode($students);

// Output is: {"1":{"subjects":{"2":{"marks":65},"3":{"marks":75}}},"2":{"subjects":{"2":{"marks":80},"3":{"marks":82}}},"3":{"subjects":{"2":{"marks":"82"},"3":{"marks":"75"}}}}
```

Then you could access your data with `$students[studentID]['subjects'][subjectId]['marks']`

Comment: This is `javascript` and there is no `javascript` tag.

Comment: You're completely right. Ill update the answer for php now